# python3 setuptools 'find_namespace_packages -> exclude' doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, python-wheel

My project structure is like:

```
xxx/
├── pysrc
│   └── xxx
│       ├── b
│       │   ├── exposed_b1
│       │   ├── exposed_b2
│       │   └── internal_b
│       ├── c
│       └── d
└── setup.py
```

I want to exclude the submodule `xxx.b.internal_b`, so i build the `setup.py` like:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_namespace_packages


setup(
    name="xxx",
    package_dir={"": "pysrc"},
    packages=find_namespace_packages(
        where="pysrc",
        include=["xxx.*"],
        exclude=["xxx.b.internal_b"]
    ),
    setup_requires=["setuptools", "setuptools-git", "wheel"]
)
```

but the final `.whl` file still included everything under the `xxx`, how should i achieve this?

---

I tried to refer the examples here [setuptools find_namespace_packages tests](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/a4dbe3457d89cf67ee3aa571fdb149e6eb544e88/setuptools/tests/test_find_packages.py#L153), but seems it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Its confusing because you have both an outer and inner directory named xxx

Answer (score -1):

For those who are struggling on this problem, i found two workarounds:

1. Explicitly list each of your sub-packages as the `find_namespace_packages -> include` parameter, **don't try to use the wildcard include all then exclude a few pattern...**, for the case i asked in the question just do:

   ```py
   from setuptools import setup, find_namespace_packages


   setup(
       name="xxx",
       package_dir={"": "pysrc"},
       packages=find_namespace_packages(
           where="pysrc",
           # DO NOT include the sub-packages you want to exclude.
           include=["xxx.b", "xxx.b.exposed_b1", "xxx.b.exposed_b2", "xxx.c", "xxx.d"],
           exclude=[]
       ),
       setup_requires=["setuptools", "setuptools-git", "wheel"]
   )
   ```

   Apparently it is cumbersome...
2. And then I debugged the `setuptools` module a bit, and found it actually does respect the `exclude` patterns: [refer here](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/1ba66c1d79bf2e89d1d7be426bde60298c9439cd/setuptools/__init__.py#L91), but after that still everything get copied/added to the final wheel, no idea why..., but the amazing part is that its return is exactly what we should provide as the `include` as i showed in the above option 1, thus a more elegant workaround could be just **nesting the `find_namespace_packages`**, like:

   ```py
   from setuptools import setup, find_namespace_packages


   setup(
       name="xxx",
       package_dir={"": "pysrc"},
       packages=find_namespace_packages(
           where="pysrc",
           include=find_namespace_packages(
               where="pysrc",
               include=["xxx*"],
               exclude=["xxx.b.internal_b"]
           ),
           exclude=[]
       ),
       setup_requires=["setuptools", "setuptools-git", "wheel"]
   )
   ```

So in option 2 we just nested the `find_namespace_packages`, and then we can use the **wildcard include all then exclude a few pattern in the inner `find_namespace_packages`**

What a solution...

---

Remember to delete the `xxx.egg-info` and the `build` dirs generated by the `bdist_wheel` command before doing the testing.